# Mutate F# [<Struct>] Record

Tags: struct, f#, record

This code shows how to make a function mutate its input - one of the things we come to F# to avoid.

```
type Age = { mutable n : int }
let printInside a = printfn "Inside = %d" a.n
let inside a =
    a.n <- a.n + 1
    a.n

let a = {n = 1}

printInside a //a = 1
inside a
printInside a //a = 2
```

That being said, how do I do the same bad thing with `[<Struct>] Record`s? I suspect that `ref` or `byref` may be involved but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
type [<Struct>] Age = { mutable n : int }
let printInside a = printfn "Inside = %d" a.n
let inside a =
    a.n <- a.n + 1
    a.n

let a = {n = 1}

printInside a //a = 1
inside a
printInside a //a = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that a mutable field can only be modified if the struct itself is mutable. As you noted, we need to use `byref` in the declaration of Age. We also need to make sure `a` is mutable and lastly we need to use the **&** operator when calling the function `inside`. The **&** is the way to call a function with a `byref` parameter.

```
type [<Struct>] Age = { mutable n : int }
let printInside a = printfn "Inside = %d" a.n
let inside (a : Age byref) =
    a.n <- a.n + 1
    a.n

let mutable a = {n = 1}

printInside a //a = 1
inside &a
printInside a //a = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I get the pattern, here is a simple example (just an `int` instead of a `struct record`) of how to mutate values passed into a function:

```
let mutable a = 1
let mutate (a : byref<_>) = a <- a + 1
mutate &a
a //a = 2
```